# Building electron app fails with Electron packager and electron builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

First of all, I created a tag and build my app with electron-packager:

```
node_modules/.bin/electron-packager . MyApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon='/home/user/Desktop/logo.ico' --asar=true --prune --overwrite
```

It worked fine! The problem is that now, for this release, I create a new tag, but I try to build my app with electron builder instead. I get the following error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught Exception: 
Error: Unable to find a valid app at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Project\dist\win-unpacke
d\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:128:9) at Module._compile (module.js:541:3
2) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10) at Module.load (module.js:458
:32) at tryModuleLoad(module.js:417:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3) a
t Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10) at run (bootstrap_node.js:360:7) at sta
rtup (bootstrap_node.js:152:9) at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

Furthermore, I try to build my app again with electron packager, but it didn't work now! I get the same problem.

I checkout my app to the previoulsy working tag, and it neither work.

Unfortunately, the code can not be distributed

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in my package.json.

I miss to add "package.json" file to my files field

Comment: im having the same issue can you be more specific? what should i do to overcome this???